# Двойной клик по кнопке

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть условная клавиатура в боте с одной кнопкой: "назад", при нажатии на которую, бот отправляет пользователя в предыдущее  меню. При двойном клике на эту клавишу, бот дважды выполнит все функции этой кнопки. Хотя по задумке хочется, чтобы второй клик мыши игнорировался.
У клавиатуры vk-api есть свойство: "one_time" с параметрами True и False.
Проблему можно решить с применением параметра True, но тогда клавиатура будет исчезать, что не очень красиво выглядит.
Есть ещё способ: добавлять к каждой кнопке какую-нибудь уникальную подпись и при первом нажатии присваивать эту подпись клавише, а при втором проверять на наличие этой подписи и если она есть - игнорировать это нажатие. Но это всё, в конечном итоге, выглядит как-то громоздко и неуверенно. Поэтому встал вопрос, а есть ли какой-нибудь ещё способ решения подобной проблемы?